# Confusion about Rank Selection for Genetic Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, ranking

I have seen other SO questions asked about rank selection for genetic algorithms, but I am still confused. I haven't really seen an answer to this, or maybe I just didn't understand it: When using the rank selection, what is the population being ranked on? I had seen some answers say it's fitness, others say it's not. If it is possible to get a snippet of code so I can better understand this would be greatly appreciated. If there are any other questions, I can answer them to provide clarity. Thank you

**EDIT: The case I am trying to solve is that I have a string I need the program to get right (I know what it is and have hard-coded it)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code snippet, the fitness function, is entirely dependent on the application.  It really defines the selection process.  Imagine a simple program for playing five-card draw (poker).  Each candidate is an algorithm that decides which cards to replace.

The fitness function might work like this: (1) remove the specified cards.  (2) repeat 100 trials: replace the cards and compute the strength of the resulting hand.  (3) return the average of the 100 trials.

That average stands as the fitness measure by which the algorithms are ranked.

Does that clear things up a little?

**FOLLOW-UP**

This means that you have to choose a similarity metric.  You'll want something that is distinct for an exact match and degrades gracefully as you get farther from the right answer.  A simple search will find the [popular ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric).

Comment: It does slightly, but I am trying to put it in perspective of my case. We are trying to figure out a specific string, and one of the ways we are supposed to select strings to be placed in the next iteration is by rank selection. All it says in the book I have, and from what I have read online, was to rank the strings, but it doesn't say what to rank them by

Comment: Then please update your question with these added details.  Most of all, what does it mean to "figure out a specific string"?  Are you trying to make your algorithm converge to a given string that you already know?

Comment: I have updated my question and yes, I have a hard-coded string that I am trying to get my program to get right by using the genetic algorithms